# Can't set user says sections to pre-existing parameters?

Tags: parameters, dialogflow-es

In API.ai I'm trying to set words in the user says section to a required parameter ("passphrase", entity name @passphrase) that I may or may not be bringing through from a previous intent.

See this for the general idea: https://discuss.api.ai/t/passing-a-variable-to-the-next-query/187/2

I've tried highlighting them and clicking @passphrase:passphrase, but instead of setting those words to the required parameter, it creates a new parameter.

The difference is the value section of the parameter needs to be #secure.passphrase not $passphrase, but it won't let me change the specified value either.
How do I change this?
[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 1):

Use a developer entity for passwords will not likely work for multiple users.  Entities in API.AI are used to recognize different words and phrases in a user query.  Users passwords will (hopefully) be different from user to user so you can't provide ahead of time a list of possible passwords for the user.

This is the perfect use case for API.AI's `@sys.any` system entity.  API.AI's `@sys.any` is used to identify any word or group of words in a user query.  In your example, I'd change the `@passphrase` entity to a `@sys.any` entity and provide as many examples as I could to help API.AI's machine learning algorithms identify when users will utter their password.

Sources:

- API.AI's `@sys.any` documentation: https://api.ai/docs/reference/system-entities#generic
- API.AI's entity documentation: https://api.ai/docs/entities

Comment: It's still having issues with the fact that it automatically creates parameters when I highlight the 'password' in the User Says section.It says the name is not unique because it's creating new parameters, see the bottom row of the image provided, where I want the top row to be the password value. 
When I delete that bottom row, it deletes the association in the User Says section.

Comment: Would I have to write @sys.any where I've put 'password' in the User Says section?